# Configuring a menu with wx.wizard

Tags: wxpython

Is it possible to configure a menubar with wx.wizard? It appears the class doesn't have a SetMenuBar method. The following fails with the error: `AttributeError: 'MyWizard' object has no attribute 'SetMenuBar'`.

```
import wx
import wx.wizard


class MyWizard(wx.wizard.Wizard):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.wizard.Wizard.__init__(self, None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="Test", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
        self.m_pages = []
        self.m_wizPage = wx.wizard.WizardPageSimple(self)
        self.add_page(self.m_wizPage)

        # Menu
        menub = wx.MenuBar()
        # File Menu
        filem = wx.Menu()
        filem.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open\tCtrl+O")
        menub.Append(filem, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menub)


    def add_page(self, page):
        if self.m_pages:
            previous_page = self.m_pages[-1]
            page.SetPrev(previous_page)
            previous_page.SetNext(page)
        self.m_pages.append(page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    wiz = MyWizard()
    wiz.RunWizard(wiz.m_pages[0])
    wiz.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `Wizard` class derives from `wx.Dialog`, and dialogs do not have menus.  If you really want one then you can try using the generic implementation in `wx.lib.agw.flatmenu`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now that I understand it derives from wx.Dialog. Probably not a big deal on Windows, but on OS X this results in a single Menu item that says "Python" at the top of the screen. I'll have to see if I can override that somehow, otherwise I'll need to implement the app without wx.Wizard.

Comment: And it turns out bundling the app (with py2app, pyinstaller, etc.) overrides the "Python" name with the name of the app by virtue of creating an Info.plist. That's good enough for my application.